# Directive that holds all elements that added it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There is no official way, I'm asking for a good practice cause I think that there are lots of pitfalls here. I want to hold a collection of elements that uses a certain directive. and use this collection inside the directive.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  Use a service which holds all the elements

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.service('elmService', function(){
    this.elements = [];
})

app.directives('myDirectives', function(elmService){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, elm, attr){
            elmService.elements.push(elm);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Not good... array will be filled each time directive loads on a view you alredy been on

Comment: Well you can save it into an object with key value pairs then and you can pass in the key from the ui attribute

Comment: Its much complex than u think .. Ill upload the answer soon